# How to restrict jenkins user to create folders at root level and not jobs?

Tags: jenkins

I am looking a way to restrict jenkins users to create folders at root level and not jobs. This should work with role based strategy.

I already have folders plugin installed but there is no way i cant restrict users at root level using that.

Comment: What is the security strategy are you using in Jenkins? https://github.com/jrichardsz/static_resources/blob/master/configureSecurity.png

Comment: @JRichardsz Security Realm is ldap and Authorization is Role based Strategy